# Class 'App\Modules\Users\UsersServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, hmvc

I am trying to work in HMVC architecture; i am working in laravel 4.2.

I install the HMVC of laravel but got some problem.

1. Class 'App\Modules\Users\UsersServiceProvider' not found

Above error occurred  while putting following code in module.json

```
{
 "enabled": true,
 "provider": [
    "App\\Modules\\Users\\UsersServiceProvider"
 ]
}
```

and UsersService Provider is as follows:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\Auth;

  class UsersServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider   
  {

   public function register()
   {
      \Log::debug("UsersServiceProvider registered");
    }

}
```

While I remove the provider section in module.json it works fine; but have another problem.

2. View can not be loaded from corresponding views folder and I wrote the route as follows: (here controller works fine)

Route::get('users',array('uses'=>'UserController@getIndex'));

```
<?php 
  class UserController extends BaseController{
    public function getIndex(){
        echo 'Yes this works.';
        return View::make('users::users');
    }
?>
```

echo 'yes this works'; // works fine
while i moved to next line of code it always in the search of Views folder if users file is not in main view then it generates error.

Can anybody tell me, whats wrong with my code; guide me to have correct way to do things in HMVC, so that i can getting things done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .php class says its in the "App\Modules\Auth"
While the .json is looking in the namespace: "App\Modules\Users"

So you have to change one to the right namespace.

Comment: Actually, following lines need to be added on composer.json 
<br>

"require-dev": {
  "itsgoingd/clockwork": "dev-master",
  "way/generators": "~2"
 },

and fire the composer update .... it works fine.... thank you everybody